# How to add a hamburger menu using css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this javascript code I am using to add a hamburger menu in my webpage

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
hamburger.addEventListener("click", mobileMenu);

function mobileMenu() {
    hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
    Menu.classList.toggle("active");
}


menuLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", closeMenu));
function closeMenu() {
    hamburger.classList.remove("active");
    Menu.classList.remove("active");
}
```

and i want to add a hamburger menu so webpage would be responsive for small devices.. no errors are occurring but still no results are being showed when i run my code.
how can i change this code in order to work

```js
const Menu = document.getElementById('navbar__list');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
/**
 * End Global Variables
 */

// build the nav
NavBuilder = () => {
  //to loop from section 1 to 4 and add sections to navigation 
  for (s = 0; s < sections.length; s++) {
    const liElem = document.createElement('li');
    //const divElem = document.createElement("div");
    const Id = sections[s].id;
    const DataNav = sections[s].dataset.nav;
    liElem.innerHTML = `<a class="menu__link" href="#${Id}">${DataNav}</a>`;
    Menu.appendChild(liElem);
  }
}
NavBuilder();


//when scroll add your-active class to section and class active to navigation bar elements
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  sections.forEach(s => {
    const topDistance = s.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    // if the distance to the top is between 0-150px
    if (topDistance >= 0 && topDistance < 150) {
      s.classList.add('your-active-class');
      // add class active to navugation in order to highlight the navigation when scrolling
      document.querySelector(`a[href="#${s.id}"]`).classList.add("active");

      // otherwise, remove the class
    } else {
      s.classList.remove('your-active-class');
      document.querySelector(`a[href="#${s.id}"]`).classList.remove("active");


    }
  });

});

//set style to highlight active navigation bar elements
const menuLink = document.querySelectorAll(".menu__link");
addStyle = () => {
  menuLink.forEach((anchor) => {
    anchor.addEventListener("click", function() {
      menuLink.forEach((anchor) => {
        anchor.classList.remove("active");
      });
      anchor.classList.add("active");
    });
  });
}
addStyle();



scrollFunction = () => {
  const menuLink = document.querySelectorAll(".menu__link");
  menuLink.forEach((anchor) => {
    anchor.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.querySelector(anchor.getAttribute("href")).scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
    });
  });
};
scrollFunction();

const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
hamburger.addEventListener("click", mobileMenu);

function mobileMenu() {
  hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
  Menu.classList.toggle("active");
}


menuLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", closeMenu));

function closeMenu() {
  hamburger.classList.remove("active");
  Menu.classList.remove("active");
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar__list {
    position: fixed;
    left: -100%;
    top: 5rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  }
  .navbar__list.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.navbar__menu ul {
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: gray;
}

.navbar__menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  transition: ease 0.3s all;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:900|Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML Follows BEM naming conventions 
      IDs are only used for sections to connect menu achors to sections -->
<header class="page__header">
  <nav class="navbar__menu">
    <!-- Navigation starts as empty UL that will be populated with JS -->
    <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the solution below I just focused on creating `<a>` elements dynamically and applying the `.active` class style by firing their `click` events. There are undefined behaviors in the solution you developed:

1. You tried to use the `sections` variable in many places even though the `<section>` element is not defined.
2. The local variable `s` used in the `for` loop is not defined using the `let` or `var` keywords.
3. You must add `<a>` elements to `<li>` elements and `<li>` elements as child nodes to `<ul>` for its current style to be applicable.
4. The page `height` must be greater than `100%` for the `scroll` event to be triggered.
5. To capture the `click` events of dynamically created elements, you need a more specialized technique than the classical method.

```js
const Menu = document.getElementById('navbar__list');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const menuLink = document.querySelectorAll(".menu__link");

/* The structure you are using does not allow the creation of <a> elements because the <section> element is not defined. */
NavBuilder = (counter) => {
  for (let s = 1; s <= counter ; s++) {
    let liElement = document.createElement('li');
    let aElement = document.createElement('a');
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(s);
    
    aElement.className = "menu__link";
    aElement.setAttribute("href", "#");
    aElement.appendChild(textNode);
    aElement.setAttribute("id", `${s}`);
    liElement.appendChild(aElement);
    Menu.appendChild(liElement);
  }
}

/* I used jQuery to catch "click" events as the <a> elements are created dynamically. */
$(document).on('click', '.menu__link', function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log(this);
  
  $('.menu__link').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});

/* The <a> elements are created when the page loads. */
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  NavBuilder(10);
});
```

```css
.navbar__menu ul {
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: gray;
}

.active {
  color: red !important;
}

.navbar__menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  transition: ease 0.3s all;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar__list {
    position: fixed;
    left: -100%;
    top: 5rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  }
  .navbar__list.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:900|Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="page__header">
  <nav class="navbar__menu">
    <ul id="navbar__list">
    <!--
      <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">First</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Second</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Thirth</a></li>
     -->
    </ul>
    
    <div class="hamburger">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```